# How can we install Apache Livy outside spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, livy

My apology if somewhere I made a mistake in my language.

I want to install the Apache Livy server on a node(VM Instance) outside the Spark cluster.
How can I do this so that LivyServer should point to the Spark cluster?

I have downloaded and installed livy on VM instance using

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/livy.git
cd livy
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

made changes in livy/conf/livy.conf

```
livy.spark.master = spark://{spark-cluster-master_IP}:7077
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster
```

livy server started using command

```
livy/bin/livy-server start
```

And trying to interact using REST api of python

```
>>> import json, pprint, requests, textwrap
>>> host = 'http://localhost:8998'
>>> data = {'kind': 'spark'}
>>> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
>>> r = requests.post(host + '/sessions', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
>>> r.json()
{u'kind': u'spark', u'log': [], u'proxyUser': None, u'appInfo': {u'driverLogUrl': None, u'sparkUiUrl': None}, u'state': u'starting', u'appId': None, u'owner': None, u'id': 2}
>>> session_url = host + r.headers['location']
>>> r = requests.get(session_url, headers=headers)
>>> r.json()
{u'kind': u'spark', u'log': [], u'proxyUser': None, u'appInfo': {u'driverLogUrl': None, u'sparkUiUrl': None}, u'state': u'dead', u'appId': None, u'owner': None, u'id': 2}
```

Showing state as dead
[image]

Log file(livy/logs/livy-umesh-server.out) not showing anything about spark session dead

```
livyserver:~$ cat livy/logs/livy-umesh-server.out
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cloudera.livy.LivyConf).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Did you download Livy? Look at its configuration files? Run the startup script and get any errors?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have edited my question and mention what I did. So please have a look

Comment: You're cloning the wrong project (last commit was years ago, and it moved to the Apache incubator}. You can find how to download and setup Livy here http://livy.incubator.apache.org/get-started/

Comment: thanks @cri
livy.spark.master = local
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster

Comment: thanks, @cricket_007 for you quick and kind response
it's working well with
```
livy.spark.master = local
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster
```

But I wanted to submit jobs on yarn of Google Dataproc cluster so where could I find the steps to configure livy?

Comment: livy.spark.master needs to be set to your remote YARN resource manager address.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the response but actually i am a little bit new to YARN. could you please tell me which address I need to set in livy.spark.master

Comment: Should just be the ResourceManager host:port of the Dataproc cluster

Comment: Hello @cricket_007,
I tried with `livy.spark.master = x.x.x.x:8088` but it throwing error
`Master must either be yarn or start with a spark, mesos, k8s, or local`
So is there any another way to set a remote YARN resource manager address?

Comment: Sorry, you need to set it equal to yarn, then in the Spark conf folder, you would edit the yarn-site.xml file to point at that address. But I would verify if you can submit a regular job outside of Livy first

Comment: @umesh were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer were you able to confirm if you can submit a regular job outside of Livy?

Answer (score 1):

To run interactive sessions with Livy you need to ensure that you have network connection between Livy and Spark Driver in both directions for the RPC calls between them. If it is your case you will see in Spark Driver logs about the problems to connect to Livy RPC server or callback timeout.

You may also want to enable more verbose logging to see the detailed behaviour of Livy.